# How to show use Page.IsBusy in xamarin.froms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I binded property `IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}` and label from my page to viewmodel property. I see value changed in label, by i can't see any busy indicator on page on android, is it right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is some confusion over the `IsBusy` property. On iOS it shows the indicator in the statusbar which is questionable because the indicator there, according to iOS guidelines is only to be shown for network activity.

On Android it doesn't seem to do anything (visually) at all. Also see this [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43589) on Bugzilla where this discussion is ongoing on what you, as a developer, can expect it to do.

When we read the [documentation page](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Page.IsBusy/) for the `IsBusy` property it says:

> Marks the Page as busy. This will cause the platform specific global
>   activity indicator to show a busy state.

So you should be able to see an activity indicator, also on Android. But in the bug mentioned earlier it is stated that it only appears if certain conditions are met or not at all when using AppCompat.

For now, if you have a requirement for this, I think it would be best to either skip over it for now until this is sorted out or implement your own visual aids.

Comment: Thank you! Will implement it with custom controls.

Answer (score 1):

The activity indicator on Android was removed as part of the transition to material design, as it was no longer inline with the design recommendations.

Comment: So what is the alternative now? you need to show that it is busy if not activity indicator, what is the better option